# nested php loop eats gigabytes of linux mint memory

Tags: php, memcached, lamp, linux-mint

```
    I have some 7 nestings for/foreach php script which crashed my computer many times, and eaten each time 200-500 Mb memory, more than 3GB in total. 

    I can not recover the memory.
```

I am using `opcache_reset();`  in the code

also have tried in command line:

```
apt clean
apt autoremove --purge
apt-get autoremove 
apt-get autoclean
apt-get clean
```

Where is the problem with php?

```
opcache_reset();
$wayA = [ 
    'way1' => [
        'pr_w1' => [1, 6, 25, 50 ], 
        'revenue_w1' => 0, 
        'profit_w1' => 0, 
        'opex_w1' => [], 
        't_r_w1' => 0,
    ],

    'way2' => [
        'price_w2'=> [ 5, 10, 25, 50, 90 ],  
        'revenue_w2'=>0, 
        'profit_w2'=>0, 
        'opex_w2'=>0, 
        't_r_w2'=>0,
    ],          
];

for ( $w=1; $w<2; $w++ ) {

    for ( $e=1; $e<=21; $e+4 ) {
        $ansA[$e][$w]=[]; 
        $tw = $tz + $e * 100;
        $tz = $tw;

        for ( $t_rr=1; $t_rr<2; $t_rr++ ) {
            $t_r=5 + $t_rr*20; //tourists

            for ( $pr_rr=1; $pr_rr<2; $pr_rr++ ) {
                $pr_r= 5+ $pr_rr*15;  //price

                for ( $opex_rr=1; $opex_rr<2; $opex_rr++ ) { 
                    $opex_r= 9 + $opex_rr*20;  //opex

                    for( $N=1; $N<=2; $N++ ) { 

                        $pr_wX_key ='pr_w'.$N; //'price_w1' = 'pr_w1'
                        $wayX_key='way'.$N; 

                        foreach ( $wayA[$wayX_key][$pr_wX_key] as $pr ) {

$pr_wX = $pr / $pr_r; 
$opex_wX = $pr_wX * $opex_r/100; 
$t_NX = $tz * $t_r/100;
$rev_wX =  $t_NX * $pr_wX;//revenue = tourist numer * price
$prof_bt_wX =  $pr_wX - $opex_wX; //profit

$pr_wX_kX = 'pr_w'.$N; 
$opex_wX_kX = 'opex_w'.$N;
$t_r_wX_kX = 't_r_w'.$N;
$rev_wX_kX = 'rev_w'.$N;
$prof_bt_wX_kX = 'prof_bt_w'.$N;
$ansA[$w][$e][$t_NX_k]=[];      
$pr_wX_k= sprintf('%g',$pr_wX);   
$opex_wX_k= sprintf('%g',$opex_wX);                                      
$ansA[$w][$e][$t_NX_k][$pr_wX_k]=[];
$ansA[$w][$e][$t_NX_k][$pr_wX_k][$opex_wX_k]=[]; 
$ansA[$w][$e][$t_NX_k][$pr_wX_k][$opex_wX_k][$pr_wX_kX] =  $pr_wX; //'pr_w1'
$ansA[$w][$e][$t_NX_k][$pr_wX_k][$opex_wX_k][$opex_wX_kX] = $opex_wX; //'opex_w1'
$ansA[$w][$e][$t_NX_k][$pr_wX_k][$opex_wX_k][$t_r_wX_kX] = $t_NX; // 't_r_w1'
$ansA[$w][$e][$t_NX_k][$pr_wX_k][$opex_wX_k][$rev_wX_kX] = $rev_wX; // 'rev_w1'
$ansA[$w][$e][$t_NX_k][$pr_wX_k][$opex_wX_k][$prof_bt_wX_kX] = $prof_bt_wX; //'prof_bt_w1'

                        } // for ( way1['price_w1' as
                    } // for( $N=0; $N<4; $N++ ) 
                } // for ( t_r_w1=5; t_r_w1<100; t_r_w
            } // for ( opex_w1_r=9; opex_w
        } // for ( price_w1=1; price_w
    } // for ( $w=1; $w<250; $w++
} // for ( $e=1; $e<10
```

I have cut/pasted some 3GB of /home files to other disk, but each time i run scrip i finish with 0 bytes of free memory in /home. Why ?

Comment: Probably some memory issue using virtual memory. Your code is so confusing, I suggest you to read "Clean code", there are good tips in this book.

Comment: Is there a way to recover lost memory. As i was trying several times, i lost 3GB from home directory today. It did not recover neither after memory test during boot, not running cmd commands above like clean, nor using php function 'opcache_reset()'

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do `$e+4` in your `for` loop -- the variable never increments and will run endlessly.

Instead do `$e+=4`.

Also, you may want to consider refactoring your code so it is more readable and, more importantly, *maintainable*. You probably won't remember what this does 6 months from now.

Comment: Is there a way to recover lost memory. As i was trying several times, i lost 3GB from home directory today. It did not recover neither after memory test during boot, not running cmd commands above like `clean`, nor using php function 'opcache_reset()' .

Comment: When you say memory, do you mean RAM or disk space? RAM should clear when you restart the server. Disk space indicates you have some kind of logging going on somewhere that is filling up.