# Firefox eats linux mint /home memory

Tags: firefox, out-of-memory, linux-mint

Os : Linux Mint 19.1 Cinamon 4.0.8

Prog Environ: Bitnami LAMP 7.3.11

Code editor: Brackets 1.14

Browser: Firefox Quantum for Linux mint 10

Something crashes the browser, OS, and after reboot, the 100-500Mb memory is lost.

The computer have crashed many times and was eaten some 4GB of memory, approx 100-500Mb each time. 
'/home' showed 0 memory after reboot, thus I was removing files little by little to other partition, and clearly saw, how each time after the crash, (using save F1 boot memory check), I was booting to 0 memory /home. This means each time some 200-600 Mb were gone.

I believed, it was PHP script, as in this question

[nested php loop eats gigabytes of linux mint memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065930/nested-php-loop-eats-gigabytes-of-linux-mint-memory)

But, now I have found that 3D javascript examples from plotly and echarts eat a lot of memory too.

Seems the Firefox browser is the reason, as it crashes when the script is running. 
Clearing cache, history, cookies everything - released approx 600Mb, thus some 3GB are lost.

How to recover the lost memory?

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint has a A graphical tool to analyse disk usage: Baobab 3.2.80

Copyright © 2005-2011 Fabio Marzocca, Paolo Borelli, Benoît Dejean, Igalia
Copyright © 2011-2012 Ryan Lortie, Paolo Borelli, Stefano Facchini

I have found that `/home/user/lampstack-X/apache2/logs`  consumed 5GB.

And some project folders contained a lot of output files for debugging not deleted by mistake - some 10GB more.

Changed to the said folders and emptied files:

```
~$ cd /home/amber3/lamp*/apache2/logs
~/lampstack-X/apache2/logs$ ls
access_log  error_log  httpd.pid
~/lampstack-X/apache2/logs$ true > error_log
~/lampstack-X/apache2/logs$ true > access_log 
~/lampstack-v/apache2/logs$ true > httpd.pid
```